# Shortcut based clipboard management

Tags: clipboard

I am aware of clipboard managers like copyq's existence, but using them requires clicking around and takes time. I woudl like something purely keyboard based, for using inside terminals.

What I have in mind is replicating shell functionality for pasting things from the clipboard.

For example, searching the history of shell commands with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>, I would like to use a shortcut to search inside the clipboard history for a pattern matching my input and paste it with a single keystroke when it is found.

Or something like using <kbd>Up</kbd> for showing commands executed before. So, depending how many times the paste shortcut would be pressed, the n-th position from the clipboard would be pasted.

Is there any tool that allows me to do things like these?

Comment: `tmux` can do things like this. See http://grota.github.io/blog/2012/05/08/tmux-clipboard-integration/